# Select Pairs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Have a table where certain rows come in couples which have a matching GUID. Just wondering how to SELECT all data from the table but ONLY if the rows exist as a couple with a matching GUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM Table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT guid
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY guid
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) q ON t.guid = q.guid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a60a9/1)** demo

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE GUID IN (SELECT GUID FROM yourtable GROUP BY GUID HAVING COUNT(*)=2)
```

The subquery will return all GUIDs that appears exactly twice, the outer query will return all rows associated to those GUIDs.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db876/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
   table t1
 , table t2
WHERE
     t1.guid = t2.guid
 AND t1.id <> t2.id
;
```

**table:** your table name

**id:** some field that you know is different for both rows